# Practical Examples: Expectation of a function with respect to a probability

Tags: machine-learning, expected-value, conditional-expectation, pattern-recognition

I have encountered the following phrasing while reading Bishop's "[Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~wurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf)":

> Although for some applications the posterior distribution over unobserved variables will be of direct interest in itself, for most situations the  posterior distribution is required primarily for the purpose of **evaluating expectations**, for example in order to make predictions.

As I know from Neural Networks, you usually want the posterior for predictions. Therefore I don't understand what the use-case for evaluating expectations would be.

If you could please help me with a couple of practical examples for where one would decide to compute expectations of functions with respect to a probability or redirect me to an explanation, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this segment mentions distributions on **unobserved variables**.
Indeed, in most applications these hidden variables are not the primary interest - for example when you make a neural network, you're interested mostly in prediction, not in outputs of hidden layers.

Another take would be that when you have a classification or regression problem, you're mostly interested in minimizing loss function - and this in probability language corresponds to minimizing loss with respect to your data generating distribution. For example check [wikipedia article on risk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_risk_minimization).